# Change Front page displays settings conditionally when user is online

Tags: plugin-development, filters, page-template, homepage

Created two pages -> Feeds and Blog

1. If the **user is online** then

   **Front Page displays** settings should point to **A static page** where **Front page** should be "Feeds" and **Posts page** should be "Blog".
2. When the **user is offline** then

   **Front page displays** settings should point to **Your latest posts**, default.

**For that particular users only.**

Comment: in the template of the home page, you can use this function to what you want https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/

Comment: it wont worked; you haven't got my question. @mmm